# Flutter Dynamic object fieldname

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to create a dynamic widget for my riverpod_hook project like

```
final value = ref.watch(trProvider)
TrText(value : value,fliedName: 'newPassword', placeHolder: 'New Password');
```

i'm trying something like that

```
class TrText extends StatelessWidget {
  const TrText({
    super.key,
    required this.value,
    required this.fieldName,
    required this.placeHolder,
    this.textStyle,
  });
  final AsyncValue<Translation> value;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final String placeHolder;
  final String fieldName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return value.when(
      data: (Translation tr) => Text(
        tr.fieldName ?? placeHolder,
        style: textStyle,
      ),
      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(placeHolder),
      loading: () => const SecondaryLoader(),
    );
  }
}
```

my translation class code:

```
class Translation {
  final int? id;
  final String? profile;
  final String? changePassword;
  final String? login;
  final String? logout;
  final String? oldPassword;
  final String? newPassword;

  Translation(
      {this.id,
      this.profile,
      this.changePassword,
      this.login,
      this.logout,
      this.oldPassword,
      this.newPassword,
      });
}
```

now i'm getting "The getter 'fieldName' isn't defined for the type 'Translation'." error.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly reference `tr` when you use `fieldName` in `Text`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return value.when(
      data: (Translation tr) => Text(
        fieldName ?? placeHolder,//tr.fieldName ?? placeHolder
        style: textStyle,
      ),
      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(placeHolder),
      loading: () => const SecondaryLoader(),
    );
  }
```